# How Do I read an Excel 2007 spreadsheet with more than 65535 rows?

Tags: c#, excel, select, excel-2007, oledb

Here's what my connection string looks like..

```
m_conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES" + (char)34, m_fileName));
```

When I do a select, I only get 65535 rows back but I know the excel spreadsheet has at least 100,000.  How Do I read the rest of the rows.  Note I have to use OLEDB, no 3rd party tools right now.

Thanks much!

edit: These are Excel 2007/2010 files I'm working with

edit2: Would seem I can actually select all the rows in the spreadsheet if I do a "Select * from worksheet" as opposed to "Select * from worksheet WHERE something"

I guess when you implement a WHERE clause, the resulting rows is capped at 65535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience, an Excel worksheet is limited to 65535 lines (Excel up to 2003, I don't know about the 2007 version).

**EDIT #1**

My guess is that the OleDB data provider perhaps needs an update to correct this issue issued from the change of this Excel's limit.

Comment: Looks like the limit in 2007 is 1,048,576 rows according to http://www.free-training-tutorial.com/how-to/excel-row-limit.html

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for providing me with this information, that is a nice change that I have never been told about. =)

Comment: Updated main post to reflect limits I've found using the select statement in oledb & excel 2007

Comment: Thanks for this information! Perhaps using a `Linq` might help solve the this problem somehow. Only throwing ideas away here. We never know where this can drive us! =P

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to read an Excel file, I recommend trying the open-source [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You should open such files and save them with compatibility mode turned off. You will get more than 64k in your queries.